# django: time range based aggregate query

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have the following models, Art and ArtScore:

```
class Art(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class ArtScore(models.Model):
    art = models.ForeignKey(Art)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

Certain user actions results in an ArtScore entry, for instance whenever you click 'I like this art', I save a certain amount of ArtScore for that Art.

Now I'm trying to show a page for 'most popular this week', so I need a query aggregating only ArtScore amounts for that time range.

I built the below query but it's flawed...

```
popular = Art.objects.filter(
    artscore__date__range=(weekago, today)
).annotate(
    score=Sum('artscore__amount')
).order_by('-score')
```

... because it only excludes Art that doesn't have an ArtScore record in the date range, but **does not exclude the ArtScore records outside the date range.**

Any pointers how to accomplish this would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like according to this: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses what you have should do what you want. is the documentation wrong? bug maybe?

> "the second query will only include
>   good books in the annotated count."

in regards to:

```
>>> Publisher.objects.filter(book__rating__gt=3.0).annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

change this to your query (forget about the order for now):

```
Art.objects.filter(
    artscore__date__range=(weekago, today)
).annotate(
    score=Sum('artscore__amount')
)
```

now we can say

> "the query will only include artscores
>   in the date range in the annotated
>   sum."